# Select query on a Hierarchy Table PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I was trying to make a recursive select query in postgreSQL, I tried to read a few articles but I couldn't really get the solution out of them... either it's multi-table hierarchy or on another dialect to which then I can't translate to Postgres.

This is what I've come up with upon now but it seems to retrieve only one column so something is not quite working

```
WITH RECURSIVE authorities(role_id, role_name, fk_above_role) AS (
SELECT role_id,role_name,fk_above_role
FROM roles
WHERE role_id=1
UNION ALL
SELECT h.id_role, h.role_name, h.fk_above_role
FROM roles h
WHERE h.role_id= h.fk_above_role
)
SELECT * FROM authorities LIMIT 2;
```

I've set the limit to 2 for just to try. So basically let's say I've got a table made like so

```
role_id   |    role_name    |   fk_above_role
1              HRManager        null
2              Recruiter        1
```

In this case the recursive query I made, was to retrieve all the HRManager sub roles, how can I do this? I'll need to get eventually also the recruiter sub roles that are considered also HRManager sub_roles. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join to the recursive CTE in the recursive part of the UNION:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE authorities(role_id, role_name, fk_above_role) AS (
  SELECT role_id,role_name,fk_above_role
  FROM roles
  WHERE role_id = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT child.id_role, child.role_name, child.fk_above_role
  FROM roles child
     JOIN authorities parent on child.fk_above_rold = parent.role_id
)
SELECT * 
FROM authorities LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been wasting already so much time on this problem. Saved my life, asa I can I will accept the answer